# How to Click on Submit button using java in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

want to click on button search...?

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp;</i>
    Search 
</button>
```

Comment: You just need to select it, for example with the classes or the DOM layout. Then you can just call the `click()` method on the `WebElement`. Have you checked out any beginner tutorial on Selenium? Their examples and tutorial cover this. Please show any research effort.

Answer (score -1):

if you use google chrome web driver you can try following way.

you can use the the class name of the button or xpath of the button.

```
    WebDriver driver;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

the way to use class name of button

```
    driver.findElement(By.className("include class name of    button")).click();
```

the way to use the xpath of the button

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("include xpath")).click();
```